# How to Exclude Layout from Display on Specific Pages in Next.js 13 App Router

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, app-router

I'm working on a personal project using Next.js 13 app router and I've encountered an issue. In my project, there's a header component that's injected into the layout.tsx file in the root directory. However, I also have a dashboard page that should have its own header, and I want to prevent the header component in layout.tsx from showing on the dashboard page. I'm familiar with achieving this using the page router, which looks like this:

```
// _app.tsx

import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

function commonLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <NestedLayout>{page}</NestedLayout>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || commonLayout

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

However, I'm new to the app router and its configuration, which seems different from what I'm used to in the page router. How can I achieve a similar effect using the app router configuration?

I have searced the internet whether there is an article that explained how to achieve this, including Next.js documentation but could not find any suitable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple layout files in combination with [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups). This allows you to organize your route segments and project files into logical groups without affecting the URL path structure. Route groups are especially useful for:

- Organizing routes into groups e.g. by site section, intent, or team.
- Enabling [nested layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts) in the same route segment level:
- Creating [multiple nested layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts) in the same segment, including multiple root layouts
- Adding a [layout to a subset of routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#opting-specific-segments-into-a-layout) in a common segment